# qDecimal library issue?

Tags: qt, decimal

I started evaluating the [qDecimal](https://github.com/semihc/qdecimal) library, but I already encountered a baffling issue:

```
QDecDouble val(9.34);
val.add(QDecDouble(0.01));
qDebug() << val.toString();
```

outputs:

> QDEBUG : UtilsTests::test() "9.340000000000000"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can'f find anything with a fast search for QDecDouble... but I am almost sure that

```
val=val.add(QDecDouble(0.01));
```

would do the difference. The way you did it, the result did not saved somewhere...

Usually these commands returns the result that you want and you have to save it somewhere...

Comment: A simple mind would not comprehend what an idiot I feel now ;( The function is defined as: QDecDouble add(const QDecDouble& o, QDecContext* c = 0) const, so HUGE thanks! To provide an excuse, it was way too late in the night...

Comment: It is not really something you have to appologoze about. For example, append function on a QStringList works the way you try to use this add... and it is just an example...

Comment: Also, simple minds are used on simplify fixed computer expresions. So, the expresion "on val do the function add" is fair and simple to be translated by a human "on val... add"... Welcome!